# How to use rowspan dynamically in rails form

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I have to display the vehicle's route,fare and stop details in table format.

table structure

```
 Route       Stops        Fare       Morning Arrival Time       Evening Arrival Time

    A            A1         100            09:00 AM                  04:00 PM
                 A2         200            10:100 AM                 05:00 PM

    B            B1         100            09:30 AM                   04:10 PM
                 B2         200            10:40 AM                   05:10 PM
                 B3         300            11:00 AM                   05:30 PM
```

I have tried Following Code, But, I didn't get table format which I mentioned above.

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Route Name</th>
    <th>Stop Name</th>
    <th>Fare</th>
    <th>Morning arrival</th>
    <th>Evening arrival</th>
  </tr>
   <% @stops.each do |stop| %>
    <% @no_of_stop = stop.route.no_of_stop %>
  <tr>

    <td rowspan = '<%= @no_of_stop %>' ><%= stop.route.route_name %></td>   
    <td ><%= stop.stop_name %></td>
    <td><%= stop.fare %></td>
    <td><%= stop.morning_arrival %></td>
    <td><%= stop.evening_arrival %></td>

  </tr>
   <% end %>

</table>
```

I Got this table like .
[image]

Please Help Me..

Comment: Added an `html` tag, as it seems more relevant than RoR here.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the content of the `@stops` instance variable? Is the goal to avoid repeatedly print the stop name but rather grouping rows visually?

Comment: @stops = Stop.all .  Stop table contains stop_name: string, fare: float, morning_arrival: time, evening_arrival: time, route_id: integer

Comment: So if I understand you right, you basically just want to avoid printing the name multiple times, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the attribute names it seems a bit like your models are laid out slightly backwards or referenced in this view.

Assuming that you have a number of `routes` and each of these routes references a series of `stops` e.g. through a `has_many` relationship it would make more sense to render the **routes** rather than the **stops** IMO:

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Route Name</th>
    <th>Stop Name</th>
    <th>Fare</th>
    <th>Morning arrival</th>
    <th>Evening arrival</th>
  </tr>

  <% @routes.each do |route| %>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="<% route.stops.count %>"><%= route.route_name %></td>
      <% route.stops.each do |stop| %>
        <td ><%= stop.stop_name %></td>
        <td><%= stop.fare %></td>
        <td><%= stop.morning_arrival %></td>
        <td><%= stop.evening_arrival %></td>
      <% end %>
    </tr>
  <% end %>

</table>
```

Of course this will only work if `a route has many stops`.

Oh, and if `route.no_of_stop` is e.g. a counter cache column, you can of course replace `route.stops.count` with it again.